# Elastic Beanstalk: `eb local run` starts containers out of order, causing startup to fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerrun.aws.json

I'm using `eb local run` to locally test out a multicontainer application that I plan on deploying to Elastic Beanstalk. Before deciding to move to EB, I was using docker-compose to spin up the containers. Here's what my docker-compose.yml looked like.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: <ECR-Repo>:web
    command: gunicorn oddstracker_admin.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - .env.staging
  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    build: nginx
    image: <ECR-Repo>:nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - web
  nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    env_file:
      - .env.staging.proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy

volumes:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
```

An important aspect (at least what I think is important) is that the `nginx-proxy` service depends on the `web` and the `nginx-proxy-letsencrypt` service depends on `nginx-proxy`. This ensured that each container would not spin up until the previous one was ready.

When I moved to EB, I was forced to write a Dockerrun.aws.json file in order to run `eb local run`. Here it is.

Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "command": [
                "gunicorn",
                "oddstracker_admin.wsgi:application",
                "--bind",
                "0.0.0.0:8000"
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "<ECR-Repo>:web",
            "name": "web"
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "<ECR-Repo>:nginx-proxy",
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/certs",
                    "sourceVolume": "Certs"
                },
                {
                    "containerPath": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
                    "sourceVolume": "Html"
                },
                {
                    "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/vhost.d",
                    "sourceVolume": "Vhost"
                },
                {
                    "containerPath": "/tmp/docker.sock",
                    "sourceVolume": "VarRunDocker_Sock"
                }
            ],
            "name": "nginx-proxy",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 443,
                    "hostPort": 443
                },
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                "web"
            ]
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion",
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                    "sourceVolume": "VarRunDocker_Sock"
                },
                {
                    "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/certs",
                    "sourceVolume": "Certs"
                },
                {
                    "containerPath": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
                    "sourceVolume": "Html"
                },
                {
                    "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/vhost.d",
                    "sourceVolume": "Vhost"
                }
            ],
            "name": "nginx-proxy-letsencrypt",
            "links": [
                "nginx-proxy"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "certs"
            },
            "name": "Certs"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "html"
            },
            "name": "Html"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "vhost"
            },
            "name": "Vhost"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/var/run/docker.sock"
            },
            "name": "VarRunDocker_Sock"
        }
    ]
}
```

When it autogenerates a docker-compose.yml to run the application, there is no way to provide a `depends_on` flag for the various services. Specifically, when I run `eb local run`, `nginx-proxy-letsencrypt` runs before `nginx-proxy` is able to finish and fails the entire process.

So my question: Has anyone found a way to solve this issue, possibly with an additional set of commands within their Dockerrun.aws.json?

Answer (score -1):

> When I moved to EB, I was forced to write a Dockerrun.aws.json ?

I don't see a reason why not to use `docker-compose.yml`. [EB supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html) docker compose:

> Docker Compose features. This platform will allow you to leverage the features provided by the Docker Compose tool to define and run multiple containers. You can include the **docker-compose.yml** file to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk.

So if you have working docker-compose file, my recommendation would be to try to use it.